# using Insert in Python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am coding a Beginners program to give the 5 first letters of the alphabet: A,B,C,D,E a number of effectiveness this number is found by choosing a 2 random numbers between 1,100 and then using the a random operation from:

```
signs = ['+','-','*','/']
```

it should give the letters a 2 numbers one for the strength and another for the effectiveness:
I am having trouble inserting the effectiveness and strength numbers into after the letters so I want something like:

```
 ['A',10,43,'B',54,67,'C',9,8,'D',2,22,'E',45,32]
```

however I am getting the result:

```
['A', 110, 110, 110, 110, 110, -72, -72, -72, -72, -72, 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E']
```

Below is my code any help is very much appreciated. This is for purely beginners coding practice afterwards I have to put this into a function:

```
import random
list_alpha = ["A","B","C","D","E"]
        operator = random.choice(operations)

print(list_alpha)
```

Comment: Your [mcve] lacks definition of `operations`.

Comment: Im not not sure I understand what you mean?

Comment: You didn't provide definition of `operations`. It's probably irrevelant to the problem, but it prohibits us from running the code.

Comment: @GingerPlusPlus they *were* actually included, just not as code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from the fact that you're always inserting the value at position `1`.

You could improve this pretty easily and fix your problem by changing a few things (note that `eval` can be dangerous!)

```
list_alpha = []

# just iterate directly over a string
for alpha in 'ABCDE':
    list_alpha.append(alpha)
    for _ in range(2):
        number1 = random.randint(1, 100)
        number2 = random.randint(1, 100)
        operator = random.choice(operations)
        answer = eval('{}{}{}'.format(number1, operator, number2))
        list_alpha.append(answer)

print(list_alpha)
```

To avoid the use of `eval` you can just put functions in a list:

```
import operator    

operations = [operator.add, operator.sub, operator.mul, operator.div]

# Then you just use this:  
answer = random.choice(operations)(number1, number2)
```

Comment: Thank You Very Much I appreciate It.